# debugging html in chrome with java applets

Tags: java, google-chrome, debugging, applet

About 3-4 month ago it become impossible to debug html pages in Chrome with Java Applet running inside of it. In the moment of integrated Chrome debugged opened, java applet hides and never appears again (but still run, if there is music playing in applet, I still hear it).

Do you know how to fix it? Till summer 2014 it was able to debug html with running java applet inside of it with no any problem.

BTW. I can freely debug the same page in Firefox with applet with no issues (but I don't like Firefox debugger).